# Plugin Bodymovin

Tags: javascript, bodymovin

I want put animation font in my web site with the plugin "bodymovin" (this pricipe is transform json files in svg), i use framework laravel. I have follow this example : https://codepen.io/airnan/project/editor/ZeNONO

I manage to find my file, an importer my js, I have this error when I want to display my json I do not see what it is? I have forgot something ?

`Uncaught TypeError: keyData.e is undefined`

And this is my js code :

```
import Bodymovin from 'bodymovin';

export default class Homepage {
  constructor(options) {

  this.animation = document.querySelector('.js-animation');
  if (this.animation) {
     this.initAnimation();
  }

initAnimation() {
     Bodymovin.loadAnimation({
     container: this.animation,
     renderer: 'svg',
     loop: true,
     autoplay: true,
     path: './img/displacement-header/data-animation.json',
     });
}
```

Comment: This usually happens when your animation/json is exported incorrectly. Try to re-export it.
You could also try to remove `renderer: 'svg'` and check if there's a different error.

Comment: Ok thanks, i will se for reexporte then, i have remove ```renderer: 'svg'``` and that did not change error.

Comment: Is there another way to test my json file to see if the problem is with my export?

Comment: You could try the linked codepen (that you can be sure of that it works) locally and use your own file instead of the default data.json.